# How to force Int32 - Int64 instead of Double with MongoDB Node JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I would like to save `int32` or `int64` values from my Atlas Trigger (NodeJS code), but when i save any value it saves it as a `Double`.

`user_collection.updateOne({"_id": "anyID"}, {$inc: {"score": 2}});`

With the above line, `score` is a type of `Double` in the database.
I would like to have it as `int64`.

How can i force the use of `int64` (or `int32`) in that case please ?

Comment: With NodeJS native driver there are Int32 and Long (for Int64) classes, which can be used to convert a number to a specific type.

Comment: hello, could you please show me an example ?

Comment: To be pedantic: you're not saving a value in that query, but incrementing one.

Comment: Yes you are right @robertklep, actually this issue comes from with any number update even using `$set`. I was using this because in my database there were Int32. When i used the above query with `$inc`, they all changed to `Double` which broke my client side expecting a `int` value.

Comment: Depends upon the MongoDB version - by default when a number is stored, it is a `double` in earlier versions and `int32` in the most recent versions. You can use the aggregate operator `$convert` to convert from one type to another.

Comment: I am using MongoDB `6.0` so i guess this is why it's now forced in `double`. But i am a bit sad that when a record is in `int32`, it's overriden and cast to `double` without letting the developer deciding so.
Also i could not find anything in the documentation to set the type... from my server it's working because i force the type to int and mongo recognize it (python, dart..) but not in Node JS.
Using a aggregation for this seems a bit heavy in my humble opinion to simply choose the type of a var..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use :

`user_collection.updateOne({"_id": "anyID"}, {$inc: {"score": parseInt(2, 10)}});`

And it will save an Int32 in your database.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/data-types/):

> **Int32**
>
> If a number can be converted to a 32-bit integer, mongosh will store it as `Int32`. If not, mongosh defaults to storing the number as a Double. Numerical values that are stored as `Int32` in mongosh would have been stored by default as Double in the mongo shell.
>
> The `Int32()` constructor can be used to explicitly specify 32-bit integers.
>
> Warning
>
> Default Int32 and Double types may be stored inconsistently if you connect to the same collection using both mongosh and the legacy mongo shell.

> **Long**
>
> The `Long()` constructor can be used to explicitly specify a 64-bit integer.

So it is really confusing. You may prefer the [Long methods](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Long.html#add) if you like to modify the value.

Note, `mongosh` is also a Node.js terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried : `Long.fromInt()` and got the following error : `{"message":"'Long' is not defined","name":"ReferenceError"}`.  
It seems that `Long` is not defined from the Atlas trigger basic dependencies, and i don't want to add external dependencies.